# PHP: Storing the result of mcrypt

Tags: php, session, encoding, character-encoding, mcrypt

I've just setup Mcrypt properly in my framework and thought it would be sweet to be able to store Encrypted sessions, but I've just can't get it to work. It

The output from Mcrypt is looking something like `Ã¾øÆ{”ò(ü´îÚÜÇW¹ËŸK­¯L‘rø?ª¶!JF£­º+Œ’Ú`, so I thought that I would need to convert it to reduce the risk of charset-related issues. I've tried `utf_8_encode` and `base_64_encode` - nothing seems to work.

Just to ensure, I've changed modes of Mcrypt to *cfb* ,*cbc* & *ofb* modes. Again, no difference.

How should I encode the output of mcrypt to make it universally work for sessions, databases and so on?

Comment: What is it you are encrypting with mcrypt?  Is it a serialized session from `$_SESSION`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's function is called `base64_encode()` not `base_64_encode()` as you have posted.  That method should work, and would be preferred.  What about it is failing, if you are indeed using the correct function name?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was unable to get it to work before I restarted the server by accident, and it just miraculously began to work without changing a line of row :)